# Erro no Modulo Django

Tags: django

Sempre que tento executar, estou recebendo o seguinte erro descrito abaixo. Já pesquisei uma solução, mas não consigo fazer que funcione.

> Exception Type:    ValueError
>       Exception Value:
>       ModelForm has no model class specified.
>       Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py in **init**, line 275
>       Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
>       Python Version: 2.7.6

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')  
def cad_professor(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfessorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context['success'] = True
    else:
        form = ProfessorForm()
    context['form'] = form
    template_name = 'envelope/cad_professor.html'
    return render(request,template_name , context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Professor

class ProfessorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class meta:
        model = Professor
```

Comment: o código está formatado exatamente como o seu?

Comment: Desculpas, consertei agr esta sim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TheuzC,

o seu `meta` na verdade é `Meta`.

Tente isso ai:

```
class ProfessorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Professor
```

Answer (score 0):

Verdade, consegui da seguinte forma

```
class Meta:
    model = Professor
    fields = '__all__'      << Django estava pedido
```

e models tinha uma declaração pra o banco errado, então quando ia acessar ele não existia e dava erro por não encontrar